# build c file with openssl by NDK under cygwin

Tags: android-ndk, openssl, cygwin

I am trying to build c file included  by ndk under cygwin

In Android.mk, I add -I/usr/include to LOCAL_FLAGS like

```
LOCAL_FLAGS := -I/usr/include
```

And I have checked that openssl does under /usr/include

But when I run ndk-build under by project dir, it output

"fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory"

I think I have specified the include directory, but not solve this problem.

Is there any other way can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some gaps in your knowledge:

- C code compiles to processor's native instruction set. Your desktop/build machine probably has a different architecture from your Android device(thus a different instruction set).
- NDK doesn't just `compile`, it `cross-compiles`. It means that the **NDK** runs on the build machine, but the executable it produces cannot run on the build machine(different instruction sets).
- All libraries on your desktop are in your desktop's processoer's instruction set. Thus, you cannot link any program build by the **NDK** using the desktop's libraries. This means:

  - No includes from '/usr/include/'
  - No libs from `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, `/lib64` or `/usr/lib64`
  - No Cygwin packages under on Windows

What you need to do is build your own `openssl` using the **NDK** and use that to link against when you build your executable.

Please note that the answer is missing a lot of information (at least 3 Bachelor's level Computer Science courses worth of information).

Comment: Do you mean even though under cygwin environment with openssl package installed, I should build my own openssl first by NDK?

Comment: @Kuan-JongWu The cygwin ssl package is for Cygwin on windows, not for Android

Comment: So can I download android openssl from github and then set it as include path then build instead of building openssl by NDK first then set link to my source code?

Comment: Probably. Depends on what you need to do exactly.